# Send SMS with Twilio

Tags: twilio

I would to use twilio to send SMS with tag instead of phone Number , and I want to choose the label for sending , the label like "AUTHMSG" received from twilio when testing for trial account

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are looking for what we call alphanumeric sender IDs. You can do this under the following conditions:

- You have an upgraded account. Free accounts cannot use this feature
- You are sending messages to a country that supports alphanumeric sender IDs
- You do not need your users to reply to you

Once you are satisfied you can do that, check out my blog post on [how to use alphanumeric sender ID](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/send-branded-sms-messages-using-twilio-alphanumeric-sender-id.html) and this support article on [getting started with alphanumeric sender ID](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181348-Getting-Started-with-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID-for-Twilio-Programmable-SMS).